# Display background image when hovering over original image

Tags: html, css

I'm after a way to display the background image when hovering over the original image, and for the background image to disappear when no longer hovering over the original image. below is a snippet of my HTML and CSS. Is there no simple CSS command that says "hide original image" or "show background image"?

```css
.wildlife img {
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 width:48%;
 height:auto;
 float:left;
 background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/300/200");
}
```

```html
<div class="wildlife">
   
<a href=""><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" /></a>
   
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use JavaScript to accomplish that

Comment: @Erick thanks. Would you know how to? Use onhover or onmouseover?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you can use JS to accomplish this. See an example at the link below:

http://jsfiddle.net/wbox6khc/52/

```
<div class="wildlife">

<a href=""><img src='http://placekitten.com/g/300/200' onmouseover="this.src='http://placekitten.com/300/200';" onmouseout="this.src='http://placekitten.com/g/300/200';"/></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add styles to the `<a>` tag when you hover on it like so:

```css
.wildlife a {
  background: url('http://placekitten.com/300/200') no-repeat 0 0 scroll;
  display: inline-block
}

.wildlife a img {
  display: inline-block;
}

.wildlife a:hover img {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wildlife">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" alt="kitty">
  </a>
</div>
```

No JS necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use pure css to do this, but you need to set `width` and `height` for your `div`, check snippet below.

```css
.wildlife{
  width:300px;
  height: 300px;
  float:left;
  content:"";
  background: url("http://placekitten.com/300/200") no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: center center;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.wildlife:hover{
  background: url("http://placekitten.com/g/300/200") no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wildlife">
</div>
```